# In CSS what is the meaning of the following selector?

Tags: css, selector

```
.class1 .class2
{
    margin: 3px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Is it a descendant selector? So it applies to all the elements with class="class1" that are inside an element with class="class2"?
Or does it apply to all elements with class="class1" and all the elements with class="class2"?

Comment: it's applies to class2 inside class1

Comment: Selects **all** .class2 in .class1, -1 because you didn't do any research, it's extremely easy to google something like this.

Comment: Read a basic CSS tutorial. You could start at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started, then choose "Selectors", which will take you to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors. A bit down on the page, you'll see section  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors#Information.3A_Selectors_based_on_relationships. There you'll see "A E: Any E element that is a descendant of an A element (that is: a child, or a child of a child, etc.)". You need to learn how to use these resources.

Answer (score 2):

IT's descendant but you are taking in the wrong way.

**WRONG**

> all the elements with class="class1" that are inside an element with class="class2"

**GOOD**

> All the elements with class="class2" that are inside an element with class="class1"

[CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) always go from `Up` to `Down` on the DOM

Answer (score 0):

```
.foo .bar {}
```

Applies to every element having the class `bar` which is inside an element having the class `foo`.

```
.foo, .bar {}
```

Applies to every element having either the class `foo` or the class `bar`.

```
.foo.bar {}
```

*Note the lack of space between classnames*. Applies to every element having **both** the class `foo` and the class `bar`.

```
.foo > .bar {}
```

Applies to every element having the class `bar` which is a direct descendent of an element having the class `foo`. So  it **would** apply to the `<p>`, but not the `<a>` in: `<div class="foo"><p class="bar"><a class="bar"></a></p></div>`.

```
.foo + .bar {}
```

Applies to every element having the class `bar` which immediately follows an element with the class `foo`. For example the `<p>`, not the `<aside>` in: `<div class="foo"></div><p class="bar"></p><aside class="bar"></aside>`

```
.foo ~ .bar {}
```

Applies to every element having the class `bar` which is a *following* sibling of element with the class `foo`. For example the `<p>` *and* the `<aside>` in: `<div class="foo"></div><div class="somethingelse"></div><p class="bar"></p><aside class="bar"></aside>`